# Mobx - Unintended Side Effect from Compute

Tags: mobx, mobx-react

Kind of new to MobX concepts here but thought I was following the rules. When I run `createProject("Foo")` I get this error:

`Error: [mobx] Computed values are not allowed to cause side effects by changing observables that are already being observed. Tried to modify: store@2.projects[..].children`

I assumed that by assigning the original nodes to `leafNodes` and `rootNodes` I'd just be making new local vars, but it thinks I'm changing the original `@observable`. I've also tried `Object.assign({}, node)` when building the aforementioned arrays with no change. How should I structure this to prevent this side-effect? I have a flat array of objects with ids and parentIds that describe a standard tree hierarchy. The `tree` function replaces the ids with the actual objects and results in the actual nested structure.

```
import { decorate, observable, action, computed } from "mobx";
import remotedev from "mobx-remotedev";
import shortid from "shortid";

class ProjectsStore {
    projects = [];
    tasks = [];

    createProject = (projectName, parentId = null) => {
        const project = {
            type: "project",
            id: shortid.generate(),
            name: projectName,
            parentId: parentId,
            children: []
        };
        this.projects.push(project);
        return project;
    };

    createTask = (taskName, parentId = null) => {
        const task = {
            type: "task",
            id: shortid.generate(),
            name: taskName,
            parentId: parentId
        };
        this.tasks.push(task);
        return task;
    };

    get tree() {
        // Separate root nodes and all others (leaf nodes)
        let leafNodes = [];
        let rootNodes = this.projects.filter(node => {
            if (!node.parentId) {
                return node;
            } else {
                leafNodes.push(node);
                return false;
            }
        });
        // Merge the tasks and non-root projects
        leafNodes = leafNodes.concat(this.tasks);

        // If the current node is a project, RECURSIVELY add the child nodes to
        // it into the .children array
        const populate = node => {
            if (node.type === "project") {
                // Search all non-root nodes to see if their parentId matches the
                // current node's id. This designates it as a child of the current node.

                // THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR HAPPENS!
                node.children = leafNodes.filter(leaf => node.id === leaf.parentId);
                // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

                for (let i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++) {
                    node.children[i] = populate(node.children[i]);
                }
            }
            return node;
        };

        // Iterate over all root nodes and return their populated trees.
        return rootNodes.map((node, n) => {
            return populate(node);
        });
    }
}

decorate(ProjectsStore, {
    projects: observable,
    tasks: observable,
    createProject: action,
    createTask: action,
    tree: computed
});

export default remotedev(ProjectsStore);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved my own issue (kind of). So, I've learned a TON about mobx and proxies trying to work this out and it seems the best solution is an architectural change. I thought I would store the nodes in a flat array and then construct the hierarchy on the fly with a recursive function. Turns out I can't change the structure in a `compute` function (the error above^^) and I can't duplicate the nodes because then it would break the `observe`-ability.

So, the solution was to keep them flat and change my React component rendering to recursively render the hierarchy. Which, *as it turns out*, keeps data and logic separate from presentation. Win-win!